# CSG failed, exception degenerate edge

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

I have an object made in blender which needs to prepared for 3D printing. It is relatively complex object (114k verts, 228k faces, 228k tris) which contains three separate meshes.

I separated the object by loose parts, checked for non-manifold geometry, converted ngons to triangles, and am now attempting to perform boolean Union on them. Blender shows `Cannot execute boolean operation`, and CMD displays `CSG failed, exception degenerate edge`.

What's going on here?

UPDATE:

Modifier seems to work without an error *if and only if* objects *don't* intersect. That is a problem, since all my objects intertwine. Object parts were designed to intersect. For instance, a person representing a sword. Sword is a bit thicker than the hole in the person's hand to ensure structural integrity of a printed model.

Comment: I think it happens when two edges align just right, try making small adjustments to the location of one object to "break them apart".

Comment: @sambler Boolean operator doesn't produce errors only when objects are not intersecting thus defeating its purpose. If I could "break objects apart", I wouldn't need boolean operator.

Comment: I had similar problem.The problem was solved by converting the tris to quads (Alt+j).